# Why does installing Ruby on Rails generate error "size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

When installing Ruby on Rails (via `gem install rails`) you may get the following error message:

```
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:109:14: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
```

There will also be many warnings like this:

```
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1333:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

and an additional error

```
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:41:8: error: redefinition of 'struct timespec'
```

Why does this happen and how can I install Rails successfully?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This happens when you have installed the wrong version of the DevKit for your version of Ruby, e.g., if you installed `DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe` into Ruby version 1.9.3.

To correct the problem, reinstall Ruby and install the correct DevKit for your version of Ruby, as indicated in the section titled "Which Development Kit?" at http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads.

Comment: Just saved me another hour of banging my head against this problem - thanks Harry !

Comment: If you have in fact downloaded the correct version of `DevKit`, but you previously installed some other version (as long as you passed [step 4](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#4-run-installation-scripts)) you may want to try to fire `<DEVKIT_INSTALL_DIR>\ruby dk.rb init --force` (it's not only `config.yml` that gets prepped in the `init` step).

Comment: also the bit version (32 or 64) needs to match ;)

Comment: you can check which bit version of Ruby you have by doing this: `$ irb` then `['foo'].pack('p').size`. 8 for 64bit, 4 for 32bit. source - https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/177435

Comment: Perfect, this saved me a lot of time. Also, if you are using ruby 187 or 193, you need to download DevKit 4.5.2 from their download archives page. Follow the detailed setup guide at: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#quick-start