# "error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative" when building MySQL Connector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, mysql-connector

```
> c:\Ruby193>ruby -v
> ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32]
> c:\Ruby193>rails -v
> Rails 3.2.13
> c:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64

> This is problem:
> C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
> creating Makefile

> make

> generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
> compiling generator.c
> In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:0,
>                  from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                  from generator.c:1:
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:109:14: error: size of array 
> 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
> In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:0,
>                  from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                  from generator.c:1:
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1333:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer > of different size [-Wint-> to-pointer-cast]
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1349:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer > of different size [-Wint-> to-pointer-cast]
> In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381:0,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
>                  from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                  from generator.c:1:
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h: At top level:
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:44:8: error: redefinition of 'struct 
> timespec'
> In file included from c:\ruby193\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../..
> /../../x86_64-w64-> mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:62,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:223,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
>                  from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                  from generator.c:1:
> c:\ruby193\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32
> /include/sys/types.h:89:8: > note: originally defined here
> In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381:0,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
>                  from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                  from generator.c:1:
> c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:51:8: error: redefinition of 'struct 
> timezone'
> In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:63:0,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:223,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
>                  from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
>                  from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
>                  from generator.c:1:
> c:\ruby193\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32
> /include/time.h:260:8: note: > originally defined here
> In file included from generator.c:1:0:
> ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function 'fbuffer_append_str':
> ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:118:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size 
> [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:118:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size 
> [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON_ASCII':
> generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast]
> generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast]
> generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON':
> generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast]
> generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-
> to-pointer-cast]
```

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15537192/1421049) might help

Comment: please update WinKit

Answer (score 2):

Quickfix for DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe

"Disable" definition of structures in `c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:44`

```
...
#if 0 && !defined(HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC)
...
#if 0 && !defined(HAVE_STRUCT_TIMEZONE)
...
```

works for me Win7-x64/Ruby193-x32

Answer (score 0):

I got here searching for "error: redefinition of 'struct timespec'". Eventually I figured out that I was using the version of devkit for Ruby 2 with Ruby 1.9. I downloaded the right version of devkit from here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and now everything works fine. Thought this info might help future users.