# Gem install jekyll failed after installation of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I've recently scrapped my previous ruby 2.0.0 and installed 1.9.3 and followed the same procedure. I installed devkit, and then proceeded to install Jekyll via

```
gem install jekyll
```

But I got the following errors and I've no idea what it means:

```
generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON':
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mHash_to_json':
generator.c:330:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mArray_to_json':
generator.c:342:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mFixnum_to_json':
generator.c:352:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mBignum_to_json':
generator.c:362:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mFloat_to_json':
generator.c:372:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mString_to_json':
generator.c:394:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mTrueClass_to_json':
generator.c:449:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mFalseClass_to_json':
generator.c:459:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mNilClass_to_json':
generator.c:469:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_configure':
generator.c:524:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:532:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:532:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:532:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:533:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:533:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:533:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:540:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:540:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:540:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:541:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:541:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:541:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:548:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:548:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:548:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:549:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:549:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:549:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:556:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:556:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:556:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:557:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:557:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:557:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:564:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:564:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:564:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:565:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:565:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:565:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'set_state_ivars':
generator.c:613:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:613:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:613:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:615:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:615:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:615:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_to_h':
generator.c:630:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_object':
generator.c:700:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:700:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:700:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_array':
generator.c:746:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:746:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:746:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_float':
generator.c:809:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_prepare_buffer':
generator.c:860:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_partial_generate':
generator.c:890:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'isArrayOrObject':
generator.c:902:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:902:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:902:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:903:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:903:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:903:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_generate':
generator.c:920:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_initialize':
generator.c:950:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_init_copy':
generator.c:968:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:969:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_indent':
generator.c:1012:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_indent_set':
generator.c:1024:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1026:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1026:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1026:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1035:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1035:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1035:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space':
generator.c:1049:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_set':
generator.c:1062:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1073:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1073:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1073:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before':
generator.c:1086:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before_set':
generator.c:1098:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1100:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1100:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1100:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1109:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1109:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1109:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl':
generator.c:1123:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl_set':
generator.c:1136:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1146:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1146:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1146:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_array_nl':
generator.c:1159:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_array_nl_set':
generator.c:1171:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1173:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1173:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1173:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1181:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1181:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1181:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_check_circular_p':
generator.c:1196:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_max_nesting':
generator.c:1208:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_max_nesting_set':
generator.c:1220:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_allow_nan_p':
generator.c:1233:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_ascii_only_p':
generator.c:1245:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_quirks_mode_p':
generator.c:1256:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_quirks_mode_set':
generator.c:1267:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_depth':
generator.c:1279:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_depth_set':
generator.c:1291:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_buffer_initial_length':
generator.c:1304:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_buffer_initial_length_set':
generator.c:1317:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

Ideas anyone?

Comment: It's failing to compile `json` which is required by Jekyll. Did you install the right 32/64-bit matching versions of Ruby and DevKit? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537191/why-does-installing-ruby-on-rails-generate-error-size-of-array-ruby-check-size

Comment: You genius, that was my bad. Do you want to post it as an answer and ill accept?