# Failed to build gem native extension - Ruby in Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I'm facing some problems at Windows 10 to install native extensions. This happened with many native gems.

```
C:\Ruby23x64\bin>gem install websocket-driver
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing websocket-driver:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/ext/websocket-driver
C:/Ruby23x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180307-13760-qpoxcg.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
generating websocket_mask-i386-mingw32.def
compiling websocket_mask.c
In file included from c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from websocket_mask.c:1:
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:131:14: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
In file included from c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from websocket_mask.c:1:
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_freeze_inline':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1360:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1361:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1362:6: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1362:27: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_object_get':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1400:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_object_make':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1414:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_typed_object_make':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1421:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_num2char_inline':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1588:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1588:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1588:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1949:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1966:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
In file included from c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from websocket_mask.c:1:
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_clone_setup':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1997:56: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1998:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1999:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1999:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_dup_setup':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2005:42: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2006:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2006:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_array_len':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2012:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2013:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2013:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_array_const_ptr':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2027:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2027:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2027:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_struct_len':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2034:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2035:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2035:26: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_struct_const_ptr':
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2041:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2041:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby23x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2041:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c: In function 'method_websocket_mask':
websocket_mask.c:26:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:26:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:26:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:30:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:30:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:30:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:31:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:31:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:31:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:32:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:32:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:32:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:35:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:35:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
websocket_mask.c:35:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
make: *** [websocket_mask.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/websocket-driver-0.7.0/gem_make.out
```

What i've already tried:

- My rb version is 2.3.3. My devkit is compatible with this version
- Execute devkitvars.bat to set my vars
- Install GCC
- Try to install dependencies with `bundle install` and with `gem install <gem name>`

Can somebody help me out with this, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537191/why-does-installing-ruby-on-rails-generate-error-size-of-array-ruby-check-size implies you likely have the wrong devkit.  Check the comments - make sure you have correct 32/64 bitness, and may need to re-run a script if you installed several versions of the devkit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does installing Ruby on Rails generate error "size of array 'ruby\_check\_sizeof\_voidp' is negative"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537191/why-does-installing-ruby-on-rails-generate-error-size-of-array-ruby-check-size)